# Android Realm.io migration: Fallback to .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()

Tags: android, realm

When migrating an Android Realm.io instance to a newer schema I provide migration steps in my Migration implementation:

```
  RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder(this)
            .schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION)
            .migration(new Migration())
            .build();
```

What I want to do in the actual migration code I want to fallback to `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` for older schema versions.

Is there any way to do that? I tried to do it with `deleteAll()` but that doesn't seem to work as some people updating from an older version of the app are getting Realm validation errors.

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

        if (oldVersion < 105) {
            realm.deleteAll();
            return;
        }

        //handle newer schema versions


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fallback" to `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` on older versions? The whole point of an migration is so it can upgrade older versions?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior, what I mean is that I don't want to write migration for all the older versions. There's a long tail of legacy with this app and we only want to support migration with couple of the newest versions for now (and keep the migration script uptodate for future). Writing migration for all the old version out there that never had a migration written for them is not possible in the timeframe we have. Hence, I want just to wipe the whole database as if we were calling the deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded in those cases but migrate on the newer ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to open a Realm in dynamic mode and ask for it's version. DynamicRealms will not trigger migrations:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder(this)
            .schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION)
            .migration(new Migration())
            .build();

// Use DynamicRealm to find version and delete it if it is too old
DynamicRealm dRealm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(config);
boolean delete = dRealm.getVersion() < 42;
dRealm.close();
if (delete) {
  Realm.deleteRealm(config);
}

Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```

Answer (score 2):

To clear the classes within the migration, you can remove all the classes that are within the Realm, and then restore classes using the same methodology that Realm uses:

```
package io.realm;

public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmConfiguration configuration = realm.getConfiguration();
        if(oldVersion < 105) {
            RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
            Set<RealmObjectSchema> classSchemas = schema.getAll();
            for(RealmObjectSchema classSchema : classSchemas) {
                schema.remove(classSchema.getClassName());
            }
        }
        Set<Class<? extends RealmModel>> currentModels = configuration.getRealmObjectClasses();
        Set<Class<? extends RealmModel>> nonExistentModels = new HashSet<>();
        for(Class<?> clazz : currentModels) {
            if(!schema.contains(clazz.getCanonicalName()) {
                nonExistentModels.put(clazz);
            } else {
                // TODO: migrate current classes that do exist
            }
        }

        for(Class<?> nonExistentClazz : nonExistentModels) {
            // partly taken from Realm 1.1.1's Realm.java : initializeRealm(Realm) method
            RealmProxyMediator mediator = configuration.getSchemaMediator(); // package internal
            mediator.createTable(modelClass, realm.sharedGroupManager.getTransaction()); // package internal
        }
    }
}
```

Although to be fair, this uses package-internal magic and Christian Melchior's answer is simpler, and doesn't rely on such magical things.

Also, I wrote it directly here, so I haven't actually ran it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something to the effect of:

```
    final RealmConfiguration.Builder builder=new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this);
    builder.schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION);
    if (SCHEMA_VERSION < 105) {
       builder.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded();
    } else {
       builder.migration(new Migration());
    }
    final RealmConfiguration config = builder.build();
```

Comment: I need the previous schema version for this. Do you know if I can get the old schema version somehow before calling the builder?

Comment: Off the top of my head: build a RealmConfiguration just to read the version: `long currentVersion = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).getSchemaVersion()`

Comment: new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build().getSchemaVersion() returns 0 every time.. :-(

Comment: Weird  Surely @Christian-Melchior 's suggestion will work

Comment: the difference between this solution and the one that is working is that the value of `SCHEMA_VERSION ` does not change in your code - it will always be the one you initialize it with, it is just a variable, it does not keep track of the previous version of realm.